# Waiting for JFrame to be loaded before continuing?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jsplitpane

I have a `JFrame` that contains two nested `JSplitPane`s. I want them to be set to an exact proportion on startup.

I can not use [`setDividerLocation(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html#setDividerLocation%28int%29) as I don't know the frame's size yet (I maximize it on startup). So, I use the proportional version, [`setDividerLocation(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html#setDividerLocation%28double%29).

**Code:**

```java
// ...
JSplitPane left = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
JSplitPane right = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
right.setResizeWeight(1); // So that I can move the dividers independently
left.setLeftComponent(scrollPane1);
right.setLeftComponent(scrollPane2);
right.setRightComponent(scrollPane3);
left.setRightComponent(right);
add(left, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(statusLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
setVisible(true);
setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
left.setDividerLocation(0.3);
right.setDividerLocation(0.7);
// ...
```

Now, sometimes this works perfectly fine, but sometimes it doesn't change the dividers. I believe this is because the frame is not loaded on screen. From the `setDividerLocation(double)` docs:

> If the split pane is not correctly realized and on screen, this method will have no effect (new divider location will become (current size * proportionalLocation) which is 0).

Is there a way to wait until the frame is "on screen"? This is probably about a few milliseconds, but it still breaks the layout on startup. I would not like to use `Thread.sleep` with a fixed value but some way that works with Swing.

**EDIT:** I tried the [hack](http://jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=27191) [Behe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1153530/behe) suggested. It did not work, so it might not be about the timing.

**EDIT 2:** I debugged some more. It appears that this is caused by my resize weight being set to 1. However this is required by my layout.

Comment: Might this be a solution? http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=27191

Comment: @Behe Nope, tried the hack but it didn't work. Might be related to something else.

Comment: Can you give an example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @Behe All code needed is in the question. Also, I found a solution, answer coming up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way. I added a `ComponentListener` to the inner `JSplitPane` that notifies me when it is resized by the frame maximizing. When that happens I can then safely set the resize weight.

```java
final JSplitPane left = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
final JSplitPane right = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
left.setDividerLocation(0.3);
right.setDividerLocation(0.3);
left.setLeftComponent(scrollPane1);
right.setLeftComponent(scrollPane2);
right.setRightComponent(scrollPane3);
left.setRightComponent(right);
add(left, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(status, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
setVisible(true);
right.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        right.setResizeWeight(1);
    }
});
setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Comment: CompnentResized could be called a number of times as the frame and content is realised, just beware...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yep, but that should be fine. I am not setting it to anything else, so it shouldn't matter as I add the listener when the window is already visible (and so content should be loaded). The one thing this weight messes up is resizing the window.  :-/